# How to access data files when running from IDE, PyInstaller and after distribution using Setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I have data file which is required to be loaded during program execution. I am using following function to access my data file:-

```
def resource_path(relativePath):
    try:
        # PyInstaller stores data files in a tmp folder refered to as _MEIPASS
        basePath = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        try:
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)), relativePath):
                basePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "multibootusb")
            elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(sys.prefix, "multibootusb"), relativePath):
                print os.path.join(sys.prefix, "multibootusb")
        except Exception:
           basePath = '.'

    path = os.path.join(basePath, relativePath)

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None

    return path
```

This works absolutely fine when running from IDE and after distributing as executable using pyinstaller. However, problem exist when my application installed using setup.py. here is a sample code I use for distributing data file usinf setup.py:-

```
data_files = [("/usr/share/applications",["data/multibootusb.desktop"]),
                  ('/usr/share/pixmaps',["data/multibootusb.png"]),
                  (os.path.join(sys.prefix,"multibootusb", "tools"),["tools/checking.gif"])])
```

I had to use `sys.prefix` as path is different on various distros.

Comment: Can you go more into detail about 'problem exists' ? What do you expect? Which platforms have which problems?

Comment: The problem exist only under linux when distributing package using setup.py. setup.py puts my data file in to `sys.prefix,"multibootusb"` directory. I am unable to find solution to check if data file exist under `sys.prefix,"multibootusb"`